# Drawing shapes using opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to practice drawing shapes using Opencv.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
#draw a red line
img = cv.line(img, (100,100), (300,300), (0,0,255),4)
#img = cv.circle(img,(447,63), 63, (0,0,255), -1)
cv.imshow('image',img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run, I get error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 269
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shapes.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv.imshow('image',img)
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

I searched various Google links, but none helped for shapes. I appreciate any help for this.

Comment: `cv2.draw.line(r0,c0,r1,c1,shape)` returns the row and column indices of a line. Investigate what has happened. `img` should have become a tuple of 1D numpy arrays: You have redefined it. Instead, use the output of `r,c = cv2.draw.line(*args)` to index into the image: `img[r,c]=[255,0,0]` draws a red line in `img`.

Comment: I did not get what you said. I am reffering standard document given by opencv. https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html can you please write elaborative answer

Comment: IIRC In OpenCV 2.4.8, neither `cv2.line`, nor `cv2.circle` return an image -- that was changed in more recent releases.

Comment: @kevinkayaks Could you please provide some reference to back up that comment?

Answer (score 1):

Error message is saying that you are passing an incorrect variable as input image. First, make sure your numpy array is created successfully, then do not try to use return value of line function, change from:

```
img = cv.line(img, (100,100), (300,300), (0,0,255),4)
```

to:

```
cv.line(img, (100,100), (300,300), (0,0,255),4)
```